# what is the best way to overload constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

in java for overload a constructor, should i write :

```
public Livre() {
    this.setAutor("");
    this.setTitle("");
}
public Livre(String a, String t) {
    this();
    this.setAuteur(a);
    this.setTitre(t);
}
```

or

```
public Livre() {
    this("", "");
}
public Livre(String a, String t) {
    this.setAutor(a);
    this.setTitle(t);
}
```

The first one has all default value in the default constructor, but the second one seems to be more widespread,  why?

Thanks

ps: sorry for my english

Comment: With the second approach, everything goes through your `Livre(String,String)` constructor, so there is a single point to put extra initialisation code in the future.

Comment: Calling `this()` in the first example makes no sense since you immediately overwrite the values of `author`and `title`.

Comment: Of cause the best way is to have one constructor only. You better provide *constant*s for default values the user of this class can use.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic, there should be `super()` instead of `this()`, that way it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Livre() {
    this.setAutor("");
    this.setTitle("");
}
public Livre(String a, String t) {
    this();
    this.setAuteur(a);
    this.setTitre(t);
}
```

This makes very little sense, since the default values you put in place by calling `this();` are overwritten by the next setters.

```
public Livre() {
    this("", "");
}
public Livre(String a, String t) {
    this.setAutor(a);
    this.setTitle(t);
}
```

This does the same as:

```
public Livre() {
    this.setAutor("");
    this.setTitle("");
}
public Livre(String a, String t) {
    this.setAutor(a);
    this.setTitle(t);
}
```

it's just to avoid code duplication.

Also: you shouldn't call setters in constructors, unless you are sure they can not be overwritten in child classes, otherwise you'll never know what they (might) do for sure.